# MySQL Error 1093: You can't specify target table

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to modify a column 'Ram' in my table 'laptop_backup'

where i want to replace for example '12GB' to just '12'

```
Update laptop_backup
set Ram=(select replace(Ram,'GB','') from laptop_backup)
```

But i get the following error:

> 12:17:29  Update laptop_backup set Ram=(select replace(Ram,'GB','')
> from laptop_backup)   Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table
> 'laptop_backup' for update in FROM clause 0.000 sec

when i modify the code as:

```
Update laptop_backup
set Ram=(select replace(Ram,'GB','') from
(select replace(Ram,'GB','') from laptop_backup)as t)
```

it throws an error as

> 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Answer (score 1):

You just want to change the string value in the same row?

You don't need a subquery at all. Just an expression that references the former value of that string.

```
Update laptop_backup set Ram= replace(Ram,'GB','');
```